# Find unique element in an array of objects using Set doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, set

I have an array of objects, and I am trying t get unique elements from it. I tried using Set to get unique elements. It doesn't work in case of array of objects, but does work in case of array of strings etc.

How can I achieve this using set?

```
let data =[{"name":"tagName2"},{"name":"tagName2"}];
console.log(data);  //[ { name: 'tagName2' }, { name: 'tagName2' } ]
console.log((new Set(data)));  //Set { { name: 'tagName2' }, { name: 'tagName2' } }
```

Comment: Those are two **different** objects. Objects are equal only when they reference to same location.

Comment: There's no interface you can override to establish equivalence - it's plain old javascript for now.

Comment: Easy to check: `({ name: 'tagName2' }) == ({ name: 'tagName2' })` yields `false`.

Comment: define the objects outside the array and push it

Comment: @azad the data actually comes from an API request in that format

Comment: @AyushGupta remove duplicate objects before creating the set

Comment: This is one of the few cases I'd bother with using lodash...  `_.uniqWith([{"name":"tagName2"},{"name":"tagName2"},{"tag":"tagName2"},{"name":"tagName3"}], _.isEqual)` will return `[{"name":"tagName2"},{"tag":"tagName2"},{"name":"tagName3"}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the array with unique objects first and then pass it to Set as shown below:

```
let data =[{"name":"tagName2"},{"name":"tagName2"}];

uniqueData=removeDuplicates(data, "name");

console.log((new Set(uniqueData)));  //Set {{ name: 'tagName2' }}

function removeDuplicates(data, param){
    return data.filter(function(item, pos, array){
        return array.map(function(mapItem){ return mapItem[param]; }).indexOf(item[param]) === pos;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [`docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether
>   primitive values or object references

As pointed out by @Tushar those two objects are different. `Set` filter outs objects that are refrencing to the same object.

For `Set` to work you need to pass in two objects refrencing the same object.Check out [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/v8po1dw5/1/) fiddle.